# Rails - Delete button with custom controller path and css class as well as confirm

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

What i got so far:

```
= button_to 'Delete', "/blog/#{@post.id}", method: 'delete', class: 'btn btn-danger'
```

However adding a `confirm: 'Are you sure'` Has no effect. Also that line is very ugly and i'd like to shorten it.

Answer (score 5):

```
    <%= button_to 'Delete', blog(@post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

Comment: `button_to` seems to only accept 3 parameters at most. I count 4 here. Or am i wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rails v4.1.8. Anthony's solution does not work for me.
I needed to change the syntax a bit:

```
<%= button_to 'Delete', blog(@post), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```